# iOS obfuscation of supporing files

Tags: ios, obfuscation

I have an sqlite table and some audio in my iOS application that I have put a lot of work and effort into, but looking through iFile or any other browser based application I can easily find these files and do whatever I want with them. If I can do this then someone else and more malicious than myself would be able to do the same.

- How can I obfuscate my files while keeping them usable?

Comment: if you obfuscate them, someone can de-obfuscate them. Why are you worried? Someone stealing your files / content? Add some legal statement and sue them if you *really* want to protect them. If you fear someone messes with your content - keep important key data on a server as well. Or if the app is offline only - why would someone want to mess with it?

Comment: take a look here https://github.com/obfuscator-llvm

Comment: Hashing the file names will not protect the content, they will still play. Even changing the extersion so they will not click-play will only protect from a 10 year-old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do depends on who you are protecting them from.

Using `NSData` "Data Protection" will protect the file only wheb the iDevice is locked—at best but is a step up.

Another method is to encrypt them with a key which you save in the keychain. on an iPhone 6s can encrypt 1Mb in 6ms, an iPhone 4s in 30 ms (using Common Crypto), so there is really no noticible speed degradation. A good candidate for this is a 3rd party library: [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor), it handes many details needed to do this right. The attacker will have to be more than a cyrious user, this may meet your needs.

You need to define the attacker you are protecting against ranging from a curious kid to a well funded government.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on how hard you want to make it, just hash all filenames so people can't see them. if thats too easy encrypt them ... I have an answer here on SO that details how to do this

Comment: maybe link that answer, hm?

Comment: Too much effort finding it :)

Comment: Why duh? Find it yourself. You are looking for a Solution. I have given you enough keywords for a search

Comment: @downvoter please comment. I gave a valid option AND a hint for another answer